# Is there a way to map multiple packages in morphia?

Tags: java, mapping, morphia

I am using Morphia for mongoDB to Java object mapping. My POJOs are present among two packages.

I learned that the way to map a package in morphia is by using

```
MORPHIA.mapPackage(package);
```

How do I map multiple packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `mapPackage()` for each package to map.